# Where the constructor is invoked when sending a transaction with no 'to' field?

Tags: solidity, evm

I understand it's possible to create a contract with a "no to field" transaction.
I suppose all the byte code was send to this special contract. But how and where the constructor was called ?

Where I can find a documentation to use the "no to field" contract ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to deploy a contract: Mist, Parity, Truffle, etc. Each of these tools will build the 'no to field ' transaction you mention.

In fact, the only way to deploy a contract is to send its byte code to address 0x0. I think this is what you mean by 'no to field'.

Every transaction has a 'to' field. It's just that it's value is zero for a contract deployment.

Comment: All byte code send to address 0x00 was executed ? With some limits ?

Comment: I don't know all the technical details but there is a block level gasLimit which, if exceeded, will cause the transaction to fail. It's discussed on page 5 of the yellow paper (http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf).  Also, one of the things the Spurious Dragon fork did was set a max size for contracts. That, I think, is detailed here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/170